# FMX Anchors issue in Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am relatively new to FMX. I need to anchor a `TImage` to the right side of a `TFrame`, so that its position is retained on different targets. While this was *very* easy in good old `Vcl` days, the FMX image does not behave as expected. As you can see from the screenshots, when I set `Anchors` to `[akTop, akRight]`, the image sets its `Position.X` to Width of its parent, effectively going out of the view. I know the answer is right in front of me, but I can't see it. Any suggestions?

Default Anchor:
[image: Default Anchor]

Anchored To The Right:
[image: Anchored to the right]

Comment: Works OK in Delphi XE3. I'll try to test this on XE7 later.

Comment: Just tested this on Delphi XE7 with Update 1 and it also Works OK. I just can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can reproduce this, on a plain form (no frame) in XE7, using either a `TImage` or a `TPanel` with an image on it. Turning on `akRight` immediately snaps the left edge of the control to the right edge of the form, putting the control off the right side of the form.

Comment: The solution appears to lie in not using anchors, but layouts (specifically, in this case, `TGridPanelLayout`). See [FireMonkey Layout Strategies](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/FireMonkey_Layouts_Strategies).

Comment: That is extreemly strange. How can you guys reproduce this but I can't. What Windows do you guys have.

Comment: @SilverWarior I have XE7 with Update one installed on Windows 8.1 x64 EnterpriseN

Comment: Have you installed the hotfix? http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014-december-hotfix-firemonkey-resize.html

Comment: Have the same problems with anchors and TImage in Delphi XE7

Comment: Still an issue under xe8